# Xquery (SQL Server 2005/2008) except / outer join?

Tags: sql-server, xml, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005, xquery

I'm using SQL Server 2005/2008 xml/xquery. I have the following xml and I want to return all the elements in `<all>` except these in `<except>`.

```sql
declare @x xml = '
<except>
  <x>1</x>
  <x>4</x>
</except>
<all>
  <x>1</x>
  <x>2</x>
  <x>3</x>
  <x>4</x>
</all>'
select @x.query('for $x in /all return $x') 
-- How to except the elements in <except>?
```

Expected result: `<x>2</x><x>3</x>`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've been trying and found one solution. Is it OK?

```
select @x.query('let $e := /all/x[not(. = /except/x)]
return $e')
```

Comment: It's perfectly fine if your node value is a simple type. If it would be a node instead of an integer you would need to do more than a general comparison, because for example `<x/> = <y/>` evaluates to `true` which might be surprising at first.

Comment: You do not need the `let/return` - just do `/all/x[not(. = /except/x)]`.